# Showing Positive Definiteness In Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\mathcal{P}_2$ be the space of all polynomials of degree less or equal to $2$ for all $f,g\in \mathcal{P}_2$ we define:
>
> $$\langle f,g \rangle=\int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)e^{-x} \,dx$$
>
> Prove it is a inner product on $\mathcal{P}_2$

It is easy to show that $\langle f,g \rangle=\langle g,f \rangle$ and $\langle \alpha f+\beta g,h \rangle=\alpha\langle  f,h \rangle+\beta\langle g,h \rangle$

To show positive definiteness we take $\langle f,f \rangle=\int_0^\infty [f(x)]^2 e^{-x} \, dx$ but how can we be sure that $\langle f,f \rangle\geq 0$ and $\langle f,f \rangle=0\iff f=0$?

Comment: $f^2 $is positive unless f = 0.  $e^{-x} $ is positive on the domain your integrating.  Their product is a positive number or its 0 if f = 0.

Comment: You forgot to mention you are considering polynomials with **real coefficients** (for complex polynomials you need to look at $\langle f,g \rangle=\int_0^\infty f(x)\overline{g(x)}e^{-x} \,dx$)

Answer (score 2):

We know that $e^{-x}> 0$ and $(f(x))^2\geq 0$. Thus, $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} (f(x))^2 e^{-x}\geq 0$ and this function is the product of continuous functions, therefore, is continuous. Then, $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} (f(x))^2 e^{-x}=0$ if and only if $(f(x))^2 e^{-x}=0$ if and only if $(f(x))^2=0$ if and only if $f(x)=0$

Answer (score 1):

The function $\varphi \, : \, x \in (0,+\infty) \mapsto \big( f(x) \big)^2 e^{-x}$ is positive on $(0,+\infty)$, continuous and such that :

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \big( f(t) \big)^2 e^{-t} \; dt = 0. $$

Therefore, this function is identically zero on $(0,+\infty)$. This implies that $f \equiv 0$.

---

Here are some ideas. Assume that $\varphi$ is not identically zero on $(0,+\infty)$. Then, there exist some point $x_0 \in (0,+\infty)$ such that $\varphi(x_0) > 0$. Because $\varphi$ is continuous, there exist $\eta > 0$ such that $\varphi > 0$ on $(x_0 - \eta, x_0 + \eta) \subset (0,+\infty)$. From the positiveness of $\varphi$, it follows that:

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \varphi(t) \, dt \geq \int_{x_0 - \eta}^{x_0 + \eta} \varphi(t) \, dt > 0. $$

This contradicts the fact that:

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \varphi(t) \, dt = 0. $$

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure why $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)g(x) e^{-x} dx < \infty$.  It may be helpful to notice that  $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^ne^{-x} dx < \infty$ This can be seen in like a billion different ways, but an integration by parts is probably the most standard.

Answer (score 1):

That $\langle f,f\rangle\ge0$ follows from the fact that $(f(x))^2 \ge 0$ (and this assumes the values of $f$ are real, as opposed to complex with possibly nonzero imaginary part) and $e^{-x}\ge0$ and the integral of a nonnegative function over $[0,\infty)$ is nonnegative.

The fact that $\langle 0,0\rangle=0$ is trivial, so proving $\langle f,f \rangle=0\iff f=0$ is a matter of proving $\langle f,f\rangle=0$ **ONLY** if $f$ is the zero polynomial.

$f$ is a continuous function since it's a polynomial function, so $x\mapsto (f(x))^2 e^{-x}$ is continuous and everywhere nonnegative. The only way a continuous nonnegative function can integrate over $[0,\infty)$ to $0$ is if it's $0$ everywhere in that interval. Since $e^{-x}$ is nowhere $0,$ we must have $(f(x))^2=0,$ so $f(x)=0.$

**Let's see if I can make another method work:**

\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty (f(x))^2 e^{-x}\,dx = \int_0^\infty (ax^2+bx+c)^2 e^{-x}\,dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^\infty \left(a^2x^4 + 2abx^3 + (b^2+2ac)x^2 + 2bcx+c^2\right) e^{-x}\, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & 24a^2 + 12ab + 2(b^2+2ac) + 2bc + c^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & (b+c+2a)^2 + (b+4a)^2 + (2a)^2.
\end{align}
This is a sum of squares, so it can be $0$ only if each term is $0;$ thus we have
\begin{align}
0 & = b+c+2a\\
0 & = b+4a \\
0 & = 2a
\end{align}
Solving this for $a,b,c$ we get $a=b=c=0.$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, can you please explain how you solve the integral in the second method (seems like it is straightforward and without integration by parts)

Comment: @gbox : $$ \begin{align} & \int_0^\infty x^4 \Big(e^{-x} \, dx\Big) = \overbrace{\int u\,dv = uv - \int v \, du}^{\large\text{integration by parts}} = \left.\vphantom{\frac11} -x^4 e^{-x}\right|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty -4x^3 e^{-x}\,dx \\ \\ ={} & 0 + 4\int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-x} \, dx \quad \text{(L'Hopital's rule was used to get the initial 0.)} \\ \\
= {} & 4\cdot 3\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-x} \, dx \quad \text{(by the same method used again)} \\  \\ = {} & 4\cdot3\cdot2 \int_0^\infty xe^{-x} \, dx \quad\text{(and again)} \\  \\ = {} & 4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx \end{align} $$

Comment: @gbox : $$ \lim_{x\to\infty} x^4 e^{-x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^4} {e^x} $$ and L'Hopital's rule can be applied to this fraction. $\qquad$

Answer (score -3):

You also have to show that the expression well-defined. To do this for given $f, g \in \mathcal{P}_2$, choose $M > 0$ such that for all $x \geq M$ we have $\lvert f(x) \cdot g(x)\rvert \leq x^5$ and $x^7 e^{-x}\leq 1$. Then we have
$$
\int_M^\infty\lvert f(x)g(x)e^{-x} \rvert \, dx \leq \int_M^\infty x^5e^{-x} \, dx = \int_M^\infty x^7e^{-x}x^{-2} \, dx \leq \int_M^\infty x^{-2} \, dx < \infty.
$$

It follows that
$$
\int_M^\infty f(x)g(x)e^{-x} \, dx <\infty.
$$

Comment: Please explain the downvotes. The question already has multiple answers, all of which are basically the same. I just tried to point out something the op might have forgotten.